# Elevator driven by flat belt in EU

Tags: copyright, expired-patent, design, intellectual-property

I am currently doing some research about elevators driven by flat belts. There seem to be a few patents regarding the use of flat belts for elevator suspension means. I found patents [US8157058](http://www.google.co.ug/patents/US8157058)and [WO2003086931-A3](http://www.google.gm/patents/WO2003086931A3?cl=en) which seem to prevent other companies building elevators driven with flat belts. But I cant find for how long the patents are valid and if the patent can be prolonged.

The patents belongs to Otis, but Schindler made a deal so they can also build belt driven elevators. The strange thing is other companies (Orona and Sodimas) are building elevators driven by belts in the EU. I hope someone can answer if its legal to build belt driven elevators in the EU with the [Contitech Poly Rope](http://www.contitech.de/pages/news/aktuelles/140821_polyrope_en.html) for example.